# TCP/Socket server in bash

Tags: bash, sockets, tcp, server, netcat

I'm trying to setup a simple TCP server in bash that can listen for request, process the data received and then send a response to the client.
Is there any way to do this properly using netcat ?

**edit - what i've have already tried :**

- Piping the output of the server to a bash script :
  `nc -kl 4444 | bash pipe.sh`
  Then, in pipe.sh, read the answer. But there is some downside to this : sometimes read is acting weirdly and do not get the full output, and I couldn't find a way to send a response to the client.
- Something more complete looking like [this](http://bluegraybox.com/blog/2013/05/04/worlds-dumbest-tcp-service/), however it causes some problems as it's meant to be interactive and wait for user input, so sometimes the server answers 2 times or simply doesn't answer anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Bash might be buffering stuff through that pipe..maybe write your own server...

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this example script](https://gist.github.com/TerryMooreII/3773579), it uses bash input/output redirection to establish a socket connection for the purpose of sending SMTP mail.  I'm sure you can re-purpose the concept for what you're doing, with the advantage that it's all bash built-ins (it does not require netcat).

The core logic is:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$MAILSERVER/$PORT 
echo -en "HELO mail.email.com\r\n"  >&3 
echo -en "MAIL FROM:$MAILFROM\r\n" >&3
echo -en "RCPT TO:$MAILTO\r\n" >&3
echo -en "DATA\r\n" >&3
echo -en "Subject: $SUBJECT\r\n\r\n" >&3
echo -en "$DATA\r\n" >&3
echo -en ".\r\n" >&3
echo -en "QUIT\r\n" >&3
cat <&3
```

The `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$MAILSERVER/$PORT` part creates the `>&3` and `<&3` redirectors; anything you output to `>&3` gets sent to the remote port, and `cat <&3` types to the console all data received from the remote server in response.

Comment: As far as I understand, I cannot listen on a port using /dev/tcp/ (as I saw [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/dev-tcp-listen-instead-of-nc-listen/49947#49947)), so the problem of sending response to a client and processing data isn't solved. However, I think this could work well as a client. Thanks for your time !